# A target array with shape (6400, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am writing CNN code but i am facing an error in this.
I am using Anaconda Python environment on pycharm 2020.1
Code is:

```
train_img,test_img,train_label,test_label = train_test_split(training_data,id,test_size = 0.20, random_state = 2)
train_img = np.expand_dims(train_img, axis=3)
#train_img = np.reshape(train_img , (6400,300,300,1))
print('train img',train_img.shape)
print('test img',test_img.shape)
train_label = np.array(train_label)
test_label = np.array(test_label)

print('train label',train_label.shape)
print('test label',test_label.shape)

# Applying CNN
# layer 1
my_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, strides = 1,padding ='valid', input_shape = (300,300, 1)))
# layer 2
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, strides = 1,padding ='valid'))
# layer 3
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# layer 4
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, kernel_size=3, strides = 1,padding ='valid'))
# layer 5
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
# layer 6
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# fully connected layer
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation= "relu"))
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation= "relu"))
my_model.summary()
# For compilation, training and making new predictions:
my_model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=['acc'])
my_model.fit(train_img,train_label,batch_size=5,epochs=10)
my_predictions = my_model.predict(test_img)
print(my_predictions)
```

Error in code is:
`ValueError: A target array with shape (6400, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss "binary_crossentropy". This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEleb.png)

I checked some methods to reshape the matrix but haven't got any matrix to reshape from 6400,1 to 6400,2 but the other way round is only possible.
Please suggest me a solution for this error.

Comment: What is the shape of train_label and train_img? I bet its (6400,1). Read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-binary-cross-entropy-log-loss-a-visual-explanation-a3ac6025181a) article on binary cross entropy - your model outputs a shape of (x, 2), where x is implied from the input. For cross entropy loss to work, train_label needs to have a shape of (x, y) and train_img needs to have a shape of (x,y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

binary classification needs the last layer to be dense with only one neuron with activation of `sigmoid`

```py
my_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation= "sigmoid"))
```